# Azure Linux VM is not starting/stopping

Tags: linux, azure

I'm trying to start/stop my Linux VM on Azure but I can neither start nor stop my VM. It stucks at "Starting virtual machine..." when starting and "Stopping virtual machine..." when stopping then throws an error and says "Failed". In my overview screen of my VM, IP address of the VM won't go away so it looks like VM is not stopping at all. How can I fix this?

Comment: can you refresh your browser and check the status of the vm in your overview?

Comment: It is not related to browser because I checked it from my friend's computer and it does exact same things.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is directly related to an Azure service situation currently occurring, and likely nothing related to your specific VM. Best to check https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status at this point, though the status page is intermittent as well right now, due to the incident.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are currently experiencing an outage in South Central US
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/
[image]

You will want to monitor the Azure Status Page for further updates. Unfortunately we cannot do anything until the problem has been mitigated by engineering. 
As a side note, we have multiple backups of all customer data so no data loss should occur. Once the issue has mitigated all Virtual Machines and data should be restored and fully functional. After the issue has been mitigated and if you are still seeing issues let us know.